# public header class constructor

Tags: c++

I am new at building distributable libraries written in C++ and I am getting a bit lost.
I have created a .cpp file with wrappers for all functions I want the library to offer users, and I have written 2 .h files, one public and one private. Below is a dummy example of my header files:

#### public.h:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    public_function();
private:
}
```

#### private.h:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    public_function();
private:
    anotherClass instanceofClass;
}
```

Note that the implementation of `public_function()` uses the "instanceofClass" in the code.
I have been able to compile with no problem the code using the private class and to compile and link the library with external programs using the public header and the compiled library. When executing that code, though, I am getting segmentation faults that I suspect have to do with lack of proper initialization of "instanceofClass".

Am I doing the right thing? Am I forced to instantiate "instanceofClass" inside the implementation of `public_function()` for it to be initialized properly, or is there anything else I should do instead?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems like you are implementing the [Pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: You shouldn't have two different definitions of the same type, or your instances will not have the correct size in memory. Use Pimpl instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare the same class 'myclass' in two different ways. There has to be a single class definition. If you want to hide the implementation's API you want to use the 'Pimpl' idiom. So your public class has a single pointer to a private class. For example:

public.h

```
class myclass_private;
class myclass {
    private:
        myclass_private* pimpl; 
    public:
        myclass();
        void public_function();
};
```

public.cpp

```
myclass::myclass() {
    pimpl = new myclass_private;
}

void myclass::public_function() {
     pimpl->private_function();
}
```

private.h

```
class myclass_private {
    public:
        void private_function(); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I had to find though that I needed to include the private.h into the public.cpp

Answer (score 1):

The `myclass` defined in public.h has no members, and is therefore sized 1 byte. The `myclass` defined in private.h encapsulates `anotherClass`, and is therefore whatever size `anotherClass` is. This inconsistency is the root of your problem.

What you ought to do is have only one header, and use a pointer (which doesn't require a class definition) to enable hiding the implementation of `anotherClass`. I'll repeat Joachim's link to [the pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) for elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a class shall not changr between different translation units. This is one of the aspects of the One Definition Rule. What you might want to donis to define the publicly visible class to have a pointer to a private implementation: the Pimpl Idiom:

```
class Public {
public:
    ...
private:
     struct Impl;
     Impl* impl_;
};
```

The `struct Impl` would only be defined in the implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

Your class lacks a proper constructor, which means that the compiler will provide a default one based on the content of the class definition.  If that definition isn't consistent accross all the code, it won't get initialized the same way everywhere, and some data may be missing.

If you want to hide the implementation details of `instanceofClass`, just do a forward declaration in the header (the private header you're providing is correct, you can use it as your public one), and provide an implementation somewhere in your code.